# Can a sentence be described as compound (rather than complex) purely based on the placement of the conjunction?

Tags: sentence, conjunctions, syntactic-analysis, complex-sentences, compound-sentences

For example:

*"Though he was late for class, he walked slowly down the corridor."* 
 This is considered a complex sentence as *"Though he was late for class"* is a dependent clause.

However, I can change the placement of *"though"* without altering the meaning or any other parts of the sentence as such:

*"He walked slowly down the corridor though he was late for class."* 
Here, there are two independent clauses (*"He walked slowly down the corridor"* and *"he was late for class"*) joined by a conjunction.

Is the second version now a compound sentence, rather than a complex one?

Answer (score 1):

> Here, there are two independent clauses ("He walked slowly down the corridor" and "he was late for class") joined by a conjunction.

*Though* is not a conjunction. Conjunctions can be remembered by the acronym **FANBOYS**: for, and, nor, but, or, yet, so.

*Though* is a subordinating conjunction. Therefore, the sentence is complex, not compound.

Comment: "Though is not a **conjunction** ... Though is a subordinating **conjunction**"--isn't there a contradiction here (unless "subordinating" is acting as a non-intersective adjective)? Shouldn't the first sentence be "Though is not a *coordinating* conjunction"?

Comment: [https://7esl.com/conjunctions-list/](https://7esl.com/conjunctions-list/) lists around 100 conjunctions. There was a belief that FANBOYS succinctly represented 'all seven' 'coordinating conjunctions', but see elsewhere on ELU to see how inaccurate this analysis actually is. CGEL shows very different behaviours within the group, and Wikipedia proposes several additional words used very similarly to some of FANBOYS.